# How to show the anticanonical divisor of geometric ruled surface is not numerical positive except $\mathbb{F}_i, i =0, 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

> The anticanonical divisor of geometric ruled surface $X$ is not numerical positive except $\mathbb{F}_i, i =0, 1$ ?

Obviously, $\mathbb{F}_0$ and $\mathbb{F}_1$ is del Pezzo surface.

Let $X = \mathbb{P}_C(E)$ where $E$ is rank two locally free sheaf on curve $C$ with genus $g$.

And we know that $[K_X] = -2h + (\operatorname{deg}(E) + 2g -2)f$, where $h, f$ are the class of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ and the fibre of structure map $p: X \to C$, respectively. And also $h$ is section of this map, with $h^2 = \operatorname{deg}(E)$.

> $(-K_X \cdot h) = \operatorname{deg}(E) + 2 - 2g \geq 0$

I confused here, we can tensor a negative degree line bundle $L$ with $E$ and then decrease the degree of $E$, then we can make the intersection number above always negative. But it seems impossible?

And if $E$ is decomposable and normalized (c.f.: Hartshorne P373) then $\operatorname{deg}(E) \leq 0$, therefore $\operatorname{deg}(E) = 0/-1, g = 0$, i.e. $X = \mathbb{F}_0$ or $\mathbb{F}_1$.

But for $E$ is indecomposable, I have no idea to prove this argument. Can anyone give me a hint or idea?

Comment: When you say "but it seems impossible" for the intersection number to be negative, what is the precise context? It shouldn't be negative if $\mathcal O_X(1)$ is in fact ample, but an abstract projective bundle can have an $\mathcal O(1)$ that is only relatively ample, not globally. Besides this, it's not entirely clear what argument you are looking for help with.

Comment: @TabesBridges For instance, $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(-n)\oplus  \mathcal{O}(-n) )= \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$,  then $K_X = -2h  - (2n + 2)f$ and $h^2 = -2n, (K_X, h) = 2n-2\geq 0$, if $n \geq 1$. But in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ there is no negative self-intersection curve, and $-K_X$ ample,  then what $h$ is?  Essentially, I want to find a curve $S$ in $X$ over a elliptic curve,  which is not fibre , with $S^2 = 0$ and $(K_X, S) \leq 0$.  Finally thanks for you help.

Comment: In this situation, $h$ is just some non-effective divisor, which can have negative self-intersection (the lack of effective curves on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ means that for $E$ effective, $E^2 = (-E)^2 \ge 0$, but the difference of two non-proportional effective divisors can have e.g. $(-2h+f)^2 = -4$). The notation $h$ of course refers to the divisor being a hyperplane section, but that interpretation doesn't work once $\mathcal O(1)$ is not ample.

Comment: Let $S = ah+bf$. Then $S^2 = 2ab + a^2\deg(E)=a(2b+a\deg(E))$, so to get $S^2=0$ we need $a=0$ or $\deg(E) = -2b/a$. Since $a=0$ implies $S$ is proportional to $f$, which you don't want, we stick to the latter (which forces $b$ to be divisible by $a$). Since we want $S$ effective, $a,b\ge 0$ and $\deg (E)$ must be negative. For $(K_X,S)$ I get $(a-2)\deg(E) -2(a+b)$. The first term will be negative for $a > 2$, and the second will always be negative, so taking $a\ge3$ and $b$ any positive multiple of $a$ should work, e.g. $S = 3h+3kf$ for $k \ge 1$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your comments. And $(K_X, S) = -a\operatorname{deg}(E) - 2b + 2a(g-1) = 2a(g -1)$, so $g = 1$. And I have one more question, for any locally free sheaf of rank 2,  $h = [C]$ for a curve in $X$, or $h$ is effective?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake last night and accidentally set $g=0$; setting $g=1$, for $(K_X,S)$ I actually get $(a-2)\deg(E)-2b$, but the conclusions end up being the same. I don't quite understand your last question. Are you asking about the divisor class $h$ associated to $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P(E)$ for any rank $2$ vector bundle $E$? The two descriptions you gave are the same thing if I'm understanding what you mean. But what I was saying a few comments back is that $h$ does not need to be effective.

Comment: @TabesBridges Oh, Yeah! I got it. Thanks for your comment.